# How can I remove duplicate values if I have a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

As an example:

I have a set of computers in which I run tests (sometimes multiple) to indicate whether they are working or not when I run the test. Say the table looks like this:

| Computer | Working? |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |
| C | 0 |
| D | 0 |
| D | 0 |
| D | 0 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 0 |
| E | 1 |

I have this table as a dataframe named WorkingComputerDf. I would like to remove duplicates for any computer that is not working (with the value 0). If a computer test is done multiple times, I would like to get rid of the instances where the computer is not working. So if we take the table above, I'd like the end result to be:

| Computer | Working? |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 1 |

Basically,  i want to keep duplicates where the computer is working. But I'd like to get rid of any case where the same computer works and doesn't work (and get rid of all the cases where the computer doesn't work), as well as any cases where the same computer repeatedly does not work.

I'm not sure if there's an easy way to use unique() or some other method?
Could I use `tidyverse`? Or would it be simplest to write an if/else statement?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(Computer) %>% filter(if(all(`Working?` == 0)) row_number() ==1 else `Working?`==1) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @akrun 
Thank you! Might I ask for a broken down version of this? I'm not sure about the row_numer()==1 step. I see that you grouped by computer to iterate over the computer IDs and you're checking to see whether or not they are working, but I'm not entirely sure what this step does.

Comment: it means that if the Working column contains all values as 0 and (if more than one 0, then return the 1st row or else subset with 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@akrun's answer works like a charm. However (partly based on your follow up question), a more readable -- but also more verbose! -- solution would be:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(computer) %>% 
  arrange(desc(working)) %>% 
  mutate(nrow = row_number(),
         sum_working = sum(working, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(nrow == 1 | sum_working > 1) %>% 
  select(computer,
         working) %>% 
  arrange(computer)
```

Comment: PS not implying that this solution is superior but someone might find this 'broken down' version helpful if only for future reference

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This seems to have worked well and I follow it. However, if I wanted to do the same thing on a data set with more variables (more columns), but I wanted to make sure after I iterate through this process, those variables remain--is there a function that I can do this? or would I have to join the new data frame back to my old data frame on a key?

Comment: Happy to help! To keep various other variables just replace `select(computer, working)` with `select(-c(nrow, sum_working))`. Alternatively, just remove the `select()` function altogether, I only added it to clean out the outcome a bit